# Is a punctuation error also a morphological error at the same time?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, orthography, morphology

Are punctuation errors counted as morphological errors?

For example, is writing *Johns car* instead of *John's car* a morphological error?

Comment: Welcome! I think it would help if you could give your working definition of morphological error and  say why you suspect it might apply to punctuation (or not).  Otherwise you are effectively asking us to write an essay on the subject. In other words, a little research on your part with your reasons for thinking one way or another, would allow us to agree or disagree. Hope this helps.

Comment: English punctuation (indeed, all English orthography) is not really related to English grammar or morphology, which is the same for literate and illiterate alike. Punctuation is something we can do when we write, but nobody ever seems to do it the same way, nor to agree on what the rules are.

Comment: You have to supply context. It would be fine to say *I went to work in the Johns car*, where *Johns* is used as an attributive noun. But if you're asking if the possessive *John's* can be written without the apostrophe and mean the same thing, it's unlikely it would be interpreted as anything other than a mistake. However, in addition to providing context, you also have to define your terminology.